# IE7 cross-domain iFrame Select issue

Tags: iframe, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-7, cross-domain

I have an iframe which contains a few select drop-down lists for data entry. I recently began noticing that mouse-clicking the select element in the iframe, the drop-down list doesn't expand. The user can click on the drop-down to set focus on it, and then scroll through the contents using up/down arrow on the keyboard, but clicking the arrow button beside the list doesn't cause it to expand & show its contents.

The parent page this frame is embedded on resides on a different domain. Initially I thought this might have something to do with javascript onfocus events within the iframe. I stripped out all of the scripting, got rid of all of the css and pared it down to a simple static html parent with a simple iframe page of static html containing just a select element. When run on the same server, the dropdown behaves normally, but when the parent page resides on one domain, and the iframe content on another, the select list cannot be expanded.

This problem only seems to occur in IE7. I've tested in IE8 & IE9 without any problems, as well in Safari, Chrome & Firefox. I found a couple of blog posts (links below) that cropped up within the last week that seem to be running in to the same problem, but no resolution.

http://johannes.jarolim.com/blog/2011/10/20/internet-explorer-cross-domain-iframes-and-unusable-select-boxes/

http://scrumpy-jack.com/post/11177166236/html-select-crazy-egg-ie-and-iframes-updated

Has anyone found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We put in place a workaround for this issue by swapping out the standard drop down menus with JQuery drop downs for IE7 users only.  We developed a script and dropped it between some IE conditional tags.

We couldn't wait for MS to issue another patch!

Comment: We ended up implementing a similar IE version-based workaround. Thanks for the suggestion & sorry for the delay in marking your response as the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this bug is due to a security update that was just released (2586448):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2628724